# Could not establish connection to "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx". Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform

When I try to connect to the GCP instance form VSCode using ssh it gives the following error :

Could not establish connection to "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx". Permission denied (publickey)

I'm using the Remote-SSH extension. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the config file there should be the following fields:

```
Host AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA
  HostName AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key
  User user_name
```

but sometimes the IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key part is missing which directs to key file location. By adding it manually and saving the config file will resolve the issue.

```
To go to the configuration file
 1. Ctrl + Shift + P
 2. Type 'Open Configuration File'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to chmod 400 the pem file.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Windows machine and have an AWS instance (in my case it's: `User ubuntu`) which I wanted to connect. This settings worked for me `.ssh/config`.

```
Host AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA
  HostName AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  User ubuntu
```

Also trying this might help:

```
To go to the configuration file
 1. Ctrl + Shift + P
 2. Kill VS Code Server on Host
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).